# asp.net : IIS Service Unavailable

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, http-status-code-503

When I attempt to update the code on a IIS webserver by replacing the old code with my new code, I receive 503 Service Unavailable replys when attempting to access any of the replaced pages on the server.

What is the cause of this failure and what steps can I take to correct such errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would do a few things:

Check the windows event logs for any web related errors.

Check the IIS logs to see if there is anything odd with the requests.

Double check the permissions of all the new files, make sure they match the files that do work.

Perform an IISReset after you deployed.

Make sure your virtual directory, or sub folders are set up correctly in IIS and didn't change in the deployment.

Answer (score 2):

If the associated ApplicationPool is disabled you also get the 'Service Unavailable' exception. (can be seen in the logs)

Answer (score 1):

Re this answer, I seem to remember having a problem like this, and it turned out that it was because I was updating the files via ftp, and the there was some conflict between the rights of the FTP user and the IIS user.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent hours looking for solution for Service Unavailable, 503 on IIS in Windows 2012 Server. In the end it helps to restart the server and everything works. Restart the IIS was not enough.

It is not the first time the restart help, the same issue was with FTP server on Windows 2012 Server.

Answer (score 0):

Could be lots of things. Did you try iisreset after updating the pages?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Eugene.  It could be lots of things.  If you publish locally, can your local IIS run the pages?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to get together with whomever has access to the server to look at the errors. Short of that, can you try putting the old code back to see if it still works?  If not, it's likely a configuration error.

Also, editing the web.config will get the application restarted. It's a useful trick when you can't access IIS.